# Bugzilla - Include Product name in sent emails

Tags: bugzilla

I am very new to Bugzilla, especially when it comes to configuring it. I am looking for a way to include the Product name in emails that are sent to users for bugs. I would like it to appears similar to this:

> Product [Bug ##] description

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit template/en/default/email/newchangedmail.txt.

Answer (score 1):

For Bugzilla 5.x check your options [here](http://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrating/templates.html#choosing-a-customization-method). If you choose to go with the second option, then create directory

> template/en/custom

copy template from

> template/en/default/email/bugmail-header.txt.tmpl

to

> template/en/custom/email/bugmail-header.txt.tmpl

and modify the later from something like 
`Subject: [[% terms.Bug %] [%+ bug.id %]] [% 'New: ' IF show_new %][%+ bug.short_desc %]`
 to something like 
`Subject: [[% terms.Bug %] [%+ bug.id %]] [[% bug.product %]] [% 'New: ' IF show_new %][%+ bug.short_desc %]`
 The `[[% bug.product %]]` is the change and it is the actual product.

After editing templates you should run checksetup.pl.